# trabajar dentro de un rango numerico en javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo este objetivo: Se tiene un control remoto de la TV, pero está defectuoso: solamente funcionan la tecla de subir un canal y la de bajar un canal. Los canales van numerados de 1 al 99, luego del 99 viene nuevamente el 1.

Dado un par de canales, se desea saber cuál es la cantidad mínima de veces a presionar un botón para ir de un canal a otro dado. Ejemplo: si se indica canal 2 y canal 5, hay que presionar 3 veces. Si se indica canal 3 y canal 98, hay que presionar 4 veces
hasta ahora tengo esto, lo que me falta es que vaya hacia atras. muchas gracias!

```
let can1 = prompt("ingrese canal inicial");
let can2 = prompt("ingrese canal final");
if(can1 >= 51 && can2<=99){
 let cant = Math.abs(can2-can1);
 alert("canales "+cant)
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema, error o dificultad que encuentras? ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Cómo piensas hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Has considerado el operador módulo (%)? En realidad es como si estuvieras contando en base 99. Puedes encontrar información en [Mozilla Developers Network (español)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)

Comment: Solo te falta el `else`, es bastante sencillo. Piensa que hacer para obtener esa "diferencia" de canales y como compensar la pérdida que tienes al restar un número de otro.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda! el problema que tengo ahora es que no encuentro la forma de hacer que, si es mas eficiente cambiar hacia arriba para dar toda la vuelta, en la alerta se muestre ese intervalo. No se si me explico, muchas graciass

Comment: Bueno, pienso que tienes que incluir un poco más de tu esfuerzo, la pista que te proporcionó el compañero @sokkian es de mucha utilidad, trabaja esa opción y presenta tus dudas con respecto al código, SO no es un lugar para resolver ejercicios de la escuela.